# Conversion of a char array to an int pointer

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a string object called `Message` that is given a string such as:

```
Message = "Hello";
```

Each character is then stored in a character array:

```
void Load()
{
    Message.toUpperCase(); // Makes all the characters uppercase
    for (int T = 0; T < Message.length(); T++) 
    {
        Storage[T] = Message.charAt(T);
    }       
 }
```

This part works fine.

Now I want to call a function that needs to be passed a integer pointer pointing to an array that maps out the bit values needed to display a character on a 5*7 LED matrix.

Normally I would be able to call `Display(H)` (`void Display(int Array[])`), and it would be fine. However, I want to use the string array so that it can be done automatically. The problem is that when using H normally it is seen as an integer pointer and it works great. Storage holds char's that are not pointers, and this creates problems.

I have tried various ways of converting it, but all seem to fail. Is this even possible?

This is what I have tried:

```
char to int:
int w = int(Storage[L]);
int* ww = &w;
```

This compiles fine, but the output is all wrong. So I am not really sure how to take this further.

Just to clarify, this works:

```
int A[] = {0x1B, 0x15, 0xE, 0xE, 0x0, 0xE, 0xE, 0xE};

Display(A);
```

But this does not:

```
String[L] = A;
int w = int(Storage[L]);
int* ww = &w;

Display(ww);
```

I'm probably doing something silly, but I can't see it.

Comment: Characters in C and C++ are the ASCII values, so the character `'A'` is the value `65` which can't be used by as bit flags for the LED display. You have to make a conversion routine that takes a character and convert it to an array with the correct values. The simplest way is to have a conversion table, so you index it with the character value and get back a static constant array of the correct values.

Comment: Why not just replace `char Storage[?]` with `int Storage[?]` ?
Your question really confuses me, I have no idea what you want to do..

Comment: What is the size of `char` and size of `int` in this context? And does the `Display()` function displays each char using its ASCII value?

Comment: `int A[] = {0x1B, 0x15, 0xE, 0xE, 0x0, 0xE, 0xE, 0xE};

    Display(A);`

What is the expected output here?

Answer (score 0):

The size of int and char are different, an int is (usually) four times the size of a char, so when you take the pointer value of a specific char in your array, you are also copying the following three chars into the int. This is probably why your output is messed up. Try the following:

```
    int i = (Storage[idx])
    int * ptrI = &i;//now ptrI points to the single integer which has been copied.
```

If you want to point to more than one integer, you would need to define an integer array (which is four times smaller than your char array)-  make sure your sizes are correct. Further than this I cannot help, since your explanation is unclear.